# How do I check if a letter has been changed in a word using PHP?

Tags: php, database, string, arrays

How do I check if a letter has been changed in a word using PHP?

For example, let's say the word `someword` changed to `somEwOrd`. How would I be able to check for the change if it's in a string or an array using PHP?

Comment: Do you want to know if that specific change has occurred or if any change in capitalization has occurred or do you want to know if ANY change has occurred? For example, would you want to detect `someword` changing to `somerord`

Comment: What's wrong with `==` or `strcmp()` > http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know *which* letters have changed...
Assuming your word is stored in a variable, you can access it via array indices in a loop to see which characters have changed.

```
$word = "someword";
$changedword = "someWoRd";

// array of changed letters by index
$changedletters = array();
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($word); $i++) {
  if ($changedword[$i] !== $word[$i]) {
    $changedletters[$i] = $word[$i];
  }
}

var_dump($changedletters);
array(2) {
  [4]=>
  string(1) "w"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "r"
}
```

Or to track changes like "from w to W"

```
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($word); $i++) {
  if ($changedword[$i] !== $word[$i]) {
    $changedletters[$i] = array("from"=>$word[$i], "to"=>$changedword[$i]);
  }
}

array(2) {
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["from"]=>
    string(1) "w"
    ["to"]=>
    string(1) "W"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["from"]=>
    string(1) "r"
    ["to"]=>
    string(1) "R"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `strtolower()`, and check if `strtolower($string1) == strtolower($string2)`.

Or `strcasecmp`, check if `strcasecmp($string1,$string2) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to compare the strings to each other twice:

1. Compare string with case insensitivity, to determine if they represent the same string regardless of case (using e.g. `strcasecmp`)
2. If #1 is true, then compare strings with case sensitivity (using e.g. `strcmp`).

If #1 is true and #2 is false, then you know you are dealing with the same string but difference letter cases.